# Dynamically load Image in ImageView in Android

Tags: android, image, dynamic

I have this database of 100+ images (of country flags) in my drawable folder.

Now I want to display the flag of the country you're currently in, in an ImageView.

I get the country with `String country_variable = address.getCountryCode();`

And I set the image with `flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.country_variable));`

As you all know R.drawable.country_variable wont't work because the compiler can't find a image named country_variable in the drawable folder.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: why don't you name each drawable with it's country code? and use an hashmap.

Comment: I did. The flags are named "fr.png", "de.png", "uk.png", etc.

Comment: didn't explain myself properly sorry.  hashmap<country_variable, int>  where int is the R.drawable.<countrycode>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use getResources().getIdentifier() to get the id by the resource name.  Something like:

```
flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + country_variable, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Tnx! It works! had to add .toLowerCase(); though. getCountryCode() returns two uppercase letters and Android doesn't allow uppercase filenames in the drawable map.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
flag.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(country_variable, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: Tnx! It works! had to add .toLowerCase(); though. getCountryCode() returns two uppercase letters and Android doesn't allow uppercase filenames in the drawable map.